# Подставить содержимое textBox

Tags: c++

```
String^ FormParams = "type=text/html&from=+ textBox2->Text&to=+ textBox3->Text&subject=+ textBox4->Text&content=+ textBox1->Text";
```

Как сделать, чтоб туда, где `+ textBox->Text` подставлялось содержимое `textBox`.
Уже многое перепробовал.

P.S. c++/cli winform mvs 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Впринципи так:

```
String^ FormParams = "type=text/html&from="+textBox2->Text+"&to="+textBox3->Text+"&subject="+textBox4->Text+"&content="+textBox1->Text;
```

Но возможно придётся воспользоваться функцией конкатенации строк